# How to remove a pair of rows based on criteria in column?

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
> tail(f,15)
        .id x  Freq
31    EOB14 1  8951
32    EOB14 2  1205
33    EOB15 1 10113
34    EOB15 2    53
35    EOCAR 1  3104
36    EOCAR 2  7012
37    EOCAL 1  3102
38    EOCAL 2  7008
49    EOC2R 1 10050
50    EOC2R 2    66
51    EOC2L 1 10029
52    EOC2L 2    61
102 DCCT_DN 0  8433
103 DCCT_DN 1  1943
```

I want to find all values based on this criteria:

```
ff=f[which(!(f[,3]<200 & f[,2]==2)),]
```

this will remove these rows from the "f" data frame:

```
    EOB15 2    53
    EOC2R 2    66
    EOC2L 2    61
```

My question is how do I create a data frame output where the corresponding 3 rows bellow would be removed as well:

```
    EOB15 1 10113
    EOC2R 1 10050
    EOC2L 1 10029
```

so that my should be like this:

```
       .id x  Freq
31    EOB14 1  8951
32    EOB14 2  1205
35    EOCAR 1  3104
36    EOCAR 2  7012
37    EOCAL 1  3102
38    EOCAL 2  7008
102 DCCT_DN 0  8433
103 DCCT_DN 1  1943


> dput(tail(f,14))
structure(list(.id = c("EOB14", "EOB14", "EOB15", "EOB15", "EOCAR", 
"EOCAR", "EOCAL", "EOCAL", "EOC2R", "EOC2R", "EOC2L", "EOC2L", 
"DCCT_DN", "DCCT_DN"), x = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 0, 1), Freq = c(8951L, 1205L, 10113L, 53L, 3104L, 7012L, 3102L, 
7008L, 10050L, 66L, 10029L, 61L, 8433L, 1943L)), row.names = c(31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 102L, 
103L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you share the data using dput(tail(f,15))? And are you saying that once you identified the rows to remove you then want all rows with that .id value gone?

Comment: Looks like we had a little back and forth with the data in the post and a slight adjustment I needed to make to the code. Is the output now what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: It looks like you adjusted the dput() to match the example. I changed my response to match.

It looks like the data you pasted with dput is a little different than what's in the example. Is this the result you are looking for:

```r
f <- structure(list(.id = c("EOB14", "EOB14", "EOB15", "EOB15", "EOCAR", 
"EOCAR", "EOCAL", "EOCAL", "EOC2R", "EOC2R", "EOC2L", "EOC2L", 
"DCCT_DN", "DCCT_DN"), x = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 0, 1), Freq = c(8951L, 1205L, 10113L, 53L, 3104L, 7012L, 3102L, 
7008L, 10050L, 66L, 10029L, 61L, 8433L, 1943L)), row.names = c(31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 102L, 
103L), class = "data.frame")

f
#>         .id x  Freq
#> 31    EOB14 1  8951
#> 32    EOB14 2  1205
#> 33    EOB15 1 10113
#> 34    EOB15 2    53
#> 35    EOCAR 1  3104
#> 36    EOCAR 2  7012
#> 37    EOCAL 1  3102
#> 38    EOCAL 2  7008
#> 49    EOC2R 1 10050
#> 50    EOC2R 2    66
#> 51    EOC2L 1 10029
#> 52    EOC2L 2    61
#> 102 DCCT_DN 0  8433
#> 103 DCCT_DN 1  1943

#// generate a vector with ids to remove
remove_id <- f[which((f[,3]<200 & f[,2]==2)),1]

#// remove those ids from the dataframe
ff <- f[-which(f$.id %in% remove_id), ]

ff
#>         .id x Freq
#> 31    EOB14 1 8951
#> 32    EOB14 2 1205
#> 35    EOCAR 1 3104
#> 36    EOCAR 2 7012
#> 37    EOCAL 1 3102
#> 38    EOCAL 2 7008
#> 102 DCCT_DN 0 8433
#> 103 DCCT_DN 1 1943
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyverse` library can help achieve this with one line of code. Notice that in what follows, parenthesis `()`, is used to order the precedence of the conditions while using the [`filter()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) function to display the desired result.

```r
library(tidyverse)
f <-structure(list(.id = c("EOB14", "EOB14", "EOB15", "EOB15", "EOCAR", "EOCAR", "EOCAL", 
                           "EOCAL", "EOC2R", "EOC2R", "EOC2L", "EOC2L", "DCCT_DN", "DCCT_DN"), 
                   x = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1), 
                   Freq = c(8951L, 1205L, 10113L, 53L, 3104L, 7012L, 3102L, 7008L, 10050L, 66L, 10029L, 61L, 8433L, 1943L)), 
                  row.names = c(31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 102L,  103L), 
                  class = "data.frame")

ff <-  f %>% filter(!((x == 2 & Freq < 200) | (x == 1 & Freq > 10000)))
ff
#>       .id x Freq
#> 1   EOB14 1 8951
#> 2   EOB14 2 1205
#> 3   EOCAR 1 3104
#> 4   EOCAR 2 7012
#> 5   EOCAL 1 3102
#> 6   EOCAL 2 7008
#> 7 DCCT_DN 0 8433
#> 8 DCCT_DN 1 1943
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>